# MongoDB oplog contains many Noops

Tags: mongodb, performance

I am trying to improve the oplog of my MongoDB server, because for now it's covering less hours, than I would like (I am not planning to increase oplog file size for now). What I found that there are many noops records in the oplog collection - { "op": "n" } + the whole document on "o". And they could take about ~20%-30% of the physical oplog size.

How could I find the reason for that, because it seems to be not ok ?

We are using MongoDB 3.6 + NodeJS 10 + Mongoose

p.s. it appears for many different collection and use cases, so it's hard to understand what is a application logic behind all these items.

Answer (score 5):

No-op writes are expected in a MongoDB 3.4+ replica set in order to support the [Max Staleness specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/max-staleness/max-staleness.rst#replica-sets) that helps applications avoid reading from stale secondaries and provides a more accurate measure of replication lag. These no-op writes only happen when the primary is idle. The idle write interval is not currently configurable (as at MongoDB 4.2).

The Max Staleness specification includes an example scenario and more detailed rationale for why the [Primary must write periodic no-ops](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/max-staleness/max-staleness.rst#primary-must-write-periodic-no-ops) as well as other design decisions.

A relevant excerpt from the design rationale:

> An idle primary must execute a no-op every 10 seconds (idleWritePeriodMS) to keep secondaries' lastWriteDate values close to the primary's clock. The no-op also keeps opTimes close to the primary's, which helps mongos choose an up-to-date secondary to read from in a CSRS.
>
> Monitoring software like MongoDB Cloud Manager that charts replication lag will also benefit when spurious lag spikes are solved.

Comment: Thx for the answer, bu i am thinking that this is a different case. In my cases it's not empty no-ops, but really duplicates of some update operations. They are really taking 20-30% of whole oplog. In my case oplog is 990 Mb and it cover ~20 hours.

Comment: @MaksimKondratyuk Apologies for missing the last comment here during the holidays. My guess is that this is a consequence of using findAndModify with retryable writes (similar to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPC-1523). With retryable writes `findAndModify` needs to write the previous state of a successful update in the oplog in order to apply that change idempotently.